# How to derive deformation gradient or displacement gradient?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method, numerical-methods, abaqus, mechanical

In one of my project, I need deformation gradient or displacement gradient for some elements in my model that made by ABAQUS software and I can't find it directly, any suggestion or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you writing a user element or user material subroutine?

Answer (score 3):

From a theoretical standpoint, the displacement gradient is equivalent to strain (assuming a structural problem).

Numerically, you can obtain the derivate of a quantity through multiplication with the derivative of the shape functions, which is often referred to as the B matrix:

```
du = B u
```

Comment: +1. As one of this site's top users in the Abaqus tag, I wonder if you've seen this question and/or if you might know the answer to it? https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2055/5